# Unable to click on checkbox using XPath and CSS

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am not able to click the checkbox, I tried some XPath and CSS  and id but I am not able to click on the checkbox

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="row">
<table id="orderNoDropdown" class="table table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="orderNoDropdown_info">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th class="checkBoxTh sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary" style="float: right;">
<input id="thCheckBox" class="checkBox" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="thCheckBox" style="margin-bottom: 19px;"/>
</div>
</th>
```

**XPath:**

```
.//*[@id='orderNoDropdown']/thead/tr/th[1]/div/label

//th/div/label
```

**CSS:**

```
 div.checkbox.checkbox-primary > label
```

Comment: Add HTML snippet and the error which you are getting.

Comment: With what language you write the tests? Pls, provide more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples the problem is that you are searching for the label being the direct descendant of the div by using `>`

Instead of this you should use ' ' which allos for any other elements at the same level - in this case an `input`

Generally you don't want to reference layout if possible so I would suggest the following:

#### XPATH

```
//input[@id="thCheckBox"]
```

#### CSS:

```
input#thCheckBox
```

As you have not indicated if other forms and form elements exist.  If they do then you would need to add additional identifier to specify this form or this row for data entry, etc.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. But i try this xpath and css same error occurred    
log4j:WARN appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Tabbie\tekafforde1\Tekafforde.com\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Tabbie\tekafforde1\Tekafforde.com\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: Purchase_multi
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following XPath,

```
//input[@id='thCheckBox']
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. But i try this xpath and css same error occurred    
log4j:WARN appenders could be found for logger (freemarker.cache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Tabbie\tekafforde1\Tekafforde.com\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Tabbie\tekafforde1\Tekafforde.com\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: Purchase_multi
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Add an "Explicit wait" to wait for an element to be visible and then use the above xpath to perform the click action.

Comment: Please Sent me full Code

Comment: <div id="autofill" class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="margin-right: -46px;">
<label class="col-md-9 control-label read-label">Fill New Qty</label>
<div class="col-md-1 checkbox checkbox-primary" style="margin-top: -7px;">
<input id="selectCheckBox" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="selectCheckBox"/>
</div>

Comment: WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
Element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityofElementlocated(By.Xpath("//input[@id='selectCheckBox']"));

Add the above code for Explicit wait then perform the click operation.